# Angular Language Service Pipe causes identifier not defined error

Tags: angular, typescript

Am I doing something wrong?
Here is a simple for loop

```
*ngFor="let group of (groups | slice: 0:5)"
[id]="group.GroupNum"
```

When I do it this way i get
`Identifier 'GroupNum' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a member`

If I remove the pipe then the error goes away. I believe the error is just with the Angular Language Service (VS Code) as the code still works as I would expect and the Angular CLI does not give me any errors.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

P.S. The interface for `groups` is defined and if I change it to `any` it still gives me the error.

Comment: Remove the parentheses?

Comment: That's just prettier doing it's thing, same error regardless

Comment: Looks like it's a bug: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/345

Comment: yup sounds about right, if you convert this to an answer i'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

```
*ngFor="let group of $any(groups | slice:0:5)"
```

$any will remove the error of "Object is unknow"

Answer (score 1):

Removing the whitespace in the argument should work.

```
*ngFor="let group of (groups | slice:0:5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a pipe replace slice then fine.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myslice' })
export class Myslice implements PipeTransform {
 transform(obj: any, begin:any,length:any): any {
  obj=obj || [];
  return obj.splice(begin,length);
  }
}
```